# mute/ban discrod.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, discord-api

Я пытаюсь сделать команды для модерации в discrod.py, код не работает , но и не выдает ошибку(и бан и мут). При этои сам бот работает и исполняет другие команды.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>', intents=intents)
@bot.command()
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Muted")
    if not role:
        role = await ctx.guild.create_role("Muted", permissions=discord.Permissions(send_messages=False))
    
    await member.add_roles(role)

@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    await member.ban(reason=reason)
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте заменить if not role на if role is None

А также укажите параметр name='Muted' в guild.create_role